# Проблема с admob InterstitialAd в приложении с AdvancedWebView

Tags: android, admob

В Android приложении на базе AdvancedWebView добавил межстраничную рекламу (InterstitialAd) от admob. Реклама отображается, но не работают ссылки, таймеры, проигрывание и т.п. Не реагирует на клики, можно только закрыть нажатием на back. Проблема возникает именно при использовании AdvancedWebView. Может кто сталкивался, как лечить?
Спасибо!

Comment: Что за `AdvancedWebView`? По идее полноэкранка это отдельная активити и на неё ничего не должно влиять...

Comment: Речь идет об этом компоненте - https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView. По идее да, отдельная активити, мало того я пробовал отобразить рекламу в отдельном интенте, результат тот же. Каким-то образом влияет именно этот компонент.

Comment: Возможно оно как то перехватывает попытки загрузить рекламу видя url в интенте... Попробуйте что-то в методах типа `public void onExternalPageRequest(String url)` сделать. Хотя бы прологгировать.

Comment: Вот тут ещё посмотрите: https://github.com/delight-im/Android-AdvancedWebView/issues/122